# Problem with saving Photo on linux ubuntu with python3

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, urllib

my function should save the photo to the specified folder, but when it works, it saves the photo to the folder where the code for this program is located and name it "\home\PycharmProjects\NeuealNetwork\DataTrain\Class1\ 1.jpg". How can i fix this?

```
import urllib.request as req
download_photo("https://www.photostock.com.mx/stock-photo-preview/132507561/1000/inh_33594_320727.jpg", "1", "match")
    
def download_photo(URL, name, tag):
    name = name + ".jpg"
    if (tag == "match"):
        name = r"\home\PycharmProjects\NeuealNetwork\DataTrain\Class1\ " + name
        req.urlretrieve(URL, name)
```

Comment: You have a "space" at the end of your string.  ¿Its correct?.

Comment: @LucasDamian Yes, it is and it works on Windows 10 correct with it

Comment: I usually add an underscore to avoid spaces:  `name = name.replace(' ','_')`